# How to generate a simple callgraph of a multiprocess application with Callgrind?

Tags: valgrind, call-graph, callgrind

I've a problem with Valgrind Callgrind.

I need to generate the call graph of an application, but this application launch several processes. I used the --trace-children=yes option of Valgrind, but that generates several different callgrind output files.

Is there a way to combine these files together to have only one call graph ? Even a tool to combine the several files will be perfect, but I didn't found anything.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to combine all files into one and switch between pids like it is with Grouping selector "ELF Object"/"Source file"? Or you want to combine several callgrind.outs into one and lose all pid separation? There can be problem with making single root of all trees (you can get a forest, not a tree, from multiple programs). But I think, this is possible with some parsing callgrind.outs and scripting and maybe using of binutils.